# Moment.js creating a popup at a specific time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, momentjs

this is the first time i am using moment.js, but im trying to create a time period for a popup or a button to appear. As this is my first time using this its very unclear through the docs how to go about this:
http://momentjs.com/docs the way i have in mind is through the duration section or manipulate

```
$('.button').hide();
if(moment.duration(9, 'hours')){
$('.button').show();
}
else{
$('.button').hide();
}
```

so something like this but i am unsure and I am trying to get it so that the time should start at 9am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using the get set functions off the site so it will look like this:

```
$('.button').hide();
if(moment().hours() >= 9 && moment().hours() <= 11){
   $('.button').show();
}
else{
   $('.button').hide();
}
```

which worked fine for momentjs

Answer (score 3):

No need to use duration. moment.js doesn't give you timeouts (Durations are just duration in time like 2 hours etc.) so just use the vanilla one:

```
function showSomething(){
   $('#something').show();
}

setTimeout(showSomething, 1000);
```

You could also of course write:

```
setTimeout(showSomething, moment.duration(2, 'seconds'));
```

But I can not see the use case in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to combine the two approaches above. I needed to activate a button during specific time  intervals: Credit to Chridam and jsg. Hers my solution:

```
    $('#myButton').hide();
        if(moment().hours() >= 13&& moment().hours() <= 17)
          {
            $('#myButton').show();
           }
      else if (moment().hours() >= 1 && moment().hours() <= 2)
{
   $('#myButton').show();
}
else{
   $('#myButton').hide();
}


    // Ability to refresh
    function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds) {
   var now = new Date();
   var then = new Date();

   if(now.getHours() > hours || (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) || now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >=  seconds) {
           then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
   }
   then.setHours(hours);
   then.setMinutes(minutes);
   then.setSeconds(seconds);

   //var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
   //setTimeout(showButton, timeout);
};
    refreshAt(13, 00, 00);
    refreshAt(17, 0, 00);
    refreshAt(1, 00, 00);
    refreshAt(2, 00, 00);
```

Answer (score 0):

To show the button at a certain time, say 11:12 hrs, you could try this:

```
$('.button').hide();

function showButton(){
   $('.button').show();
};

function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds) {
   var now = new Date();
   var then = new Date();

   if(now.getHours() > hours || (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) || now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >=  seconds) {
           then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
   }
   then.setHours(hours);
   then.setMinutes(minutes);
   then.setSeconds(seconds);

   var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
   setTimeout(showButton, timeout);
};

refreshAt(11, 12, 00);
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/wn5chbLe/)**